# Debugging amf remote calls (from flex 4) in PHP Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, flex4, xdebug, amfphp

I have installed and setup xdebug to debug php application. However I was wonder is it possible to debug the remote calls? I am using amfphp, I want to put break points and debug the code when the flex application calls the service. Is it possible? how to do it? Or Is there any way to simulate remote call called from flex 4 withing eclipse?

Thanks in Advance

[edit]
I have used xdebug pugin for firefox and chrome extension but both seems not working after I have installed them. Basically there is no hint/clue/document explaining how to use them, sadly. Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have downloaded https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/ for firefox and I had no clue on how to use it but I realized that I have removed the plugin bar which I usually disable/hide. I enabled that plug-in bar and it started appearing on the bottom of the browser and now i am able to debug :)

Any way I have found chrome extension as well https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc but i yet to figure out how to enable that, because it says the extension button will appear in the context and I have no clue when that comes. May be when I set chrome as default browser and it will pick up when flex launches the app. let me see